# Flex 3: ColorPicker Customization

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex3, color-picker

I am using a ColorPicker control in Flex 3.6 project, and I want to customize it like this:

[image]

Basically removing the border from the ColorPicker selector button and reducing the gap size between the selector and swatch pallete to zero.

Is that possible at all?

I've searched all the attributes and styles of the ColorPicker w/o success...

Many thanks!

Ofer

Answer (score 0):

You can customize components like this one by using the mx_internal namespace. Add the below to your imports:

```
import mx.core.mx_internal;
use namespace mx_internal;
```

Now you can access parts of the component you couldn't before. For instance, I needed to add a "Preferences" button to the ColorPicker's SwatchPanel in the empty space to the right.

I created a custom component that extended ColorPicker and added an EventListener for DropdownEvent.OPEN. In the event handler method, I got the SwatchPanel like this:

```
var swatchPanel:SwatchPanel = this.mx_internal::dropdown;
```

I then used swatchPanel.addChildAt(...) to add my preferences button. Easy!

You should be able to do something similar by overriding the createChildren method and messing with either its children or mx_internal properties.